Why is 'New-ServicePrincipal' not recognized despite importing ExchangeOnlineManagement module?
If you search for New-ServicePrincipal, 1001 pages will tell you to import the command or module first.  So
Install-Module -name ExchangeOnlineManagement

or
Import-Module -name ExchangeOnlineManagement

and seeing no errors or warnings from either command, then
New-ServicePrincipal -AppId ...

will work.  But after running both Import-Module and Install-Module commands above, I still get:
New-ServicePrincipal: The term 'New-ServicePrincipal' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

What else do I need?

May I suggest "Why is 'New-ServicePrincipal' not recognized despite importing ExchangeOnlineManagement module?" might be a better title for your question because it gives more context, is less vague, and helps distinguish your question from other questions on this site. (...which is what a good title should do.)

Seems reasonable; thanks.

The error usually occurs if the signed-in user does not have required permissions or roles to perform the operation.
Initially, I too got same error when I ran those commands in my environment without connecting to Exchange Online:
Install-Module -name ExchangeOnlineManagement
Import-Module -name ExchangeOnlineManagement
New-ServicePrincipal -AppId xxxxxxxx -ObjectId xxxxxxxxx

Response:

To resolve the error, make sure to connect with Exchange Online by signing in with user having either Exchange Administrator or Role Management role.
In my case, I connected to Exchange Online with user having "Exchange Administrator" role and ran the command successfully like this:
Connect-ExchangeOnline 
New-ServicePrincipal -AppId xxxxxxxx -ObjectId xxxxxxxxx

Response:

Reference:
New-ServicePrincipal : The term 'New-ServicePrincipal' is not recognized- Microsoft Q&A by Andy David - MVP
